# How does facebook rewrite URLs in Chrome & Firefox?

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, google-chrome

Facebook is almost completely AJAX, and I'm aware in older browsers and IE9, Facebook uses the hash tag to rewrite unique URLs, like...

```
http://www.facebook.com/home.php#!/?sk=welcome

http://www.facebook.com/home.php#!/?abc123
```

However, in Google Chrome and Firefox 4, Facebook is using something different, and rewriting to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/?sk=inbox

http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=bd
```

All completely in AJAX, modifying the URL and not even just whats after the hash tag (which never gets sent to the server.)

Comment: It not because IE9 isn't modern, it is. Its because IE9 doesn't use web-kit; and why should they have to.

Comment: That's not true. pushState is part of HTML5 and also Firefox is a Gecko browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using the new [HTML5 history API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html), in particular the `history.pushState` method.

It allows to change the path, query or fragment part of an URL.

Comment: Which, of course, is only available in modern browsers and not IE9.